# Is there a way to use Rust-Cargo to link SOME OF THE dependency crates dynamically?

Tags: rust, dll, linker, rust-cargo, rlib

I have a rust project, it has the following structure:

```
├─engine
│  │  Cargo.lock
│  │  Cargo.toml
│  │
│  └─src
│          lib.rs
│
├─sandbox
│  │  build.rs
│  │  Cargo.toml
│  │
│  └─src
│          main.rs
│
└─test_static
    │  Cargo.toml
    │
    └─src
            lib.rs
```

The crate `sandbox` is a bin crate, `engine` is designed to be a dylib, and `test_static` is a rlib.

In `sandbox/cargo.toml`:

```ini
[package]
name = "sandbox"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"
build = "build.rs"

[dependencies]
prefer-dynamic = "0"
engine = { path = "../engine" }
test_static = { path = "../test_static" }
```

I want to build crate `engine` as a dylib, `test_static` as an rlib, and build `sandbox`, with `test_static` statically linked and `engine` dynamically linked.

To achieve my goal, I used the following `rustc` commands:

```bash
rustc --crate-name engine engine\src\lib.rs --crate-type dylib -C prefer-dynamic
rustc --crate-name test_static test_static\src\lib.rs --crate-type rlib
rustc sandbox\src\main.rs --crate-type bin --extern engine='engine.dll' --extern test_static='libtest_static.rlib'
```

Those commands worked just fine, but I wonder if there is a way to achieve this by Cargo... When using command 'cargo build' in project root directory, I always get a binary that links 2 dependencies statically.

I searched for official docs, RFCs, but I got nothing, seems that the dependencies must be either all-static (by default) or auto-dynamic (using RUSTFLAGS='-C prefer-dynamic', which will cause the rust to build everything dynamically if possible).

Is there any Cargo.toml settings syntax to specify how to link the dependency crate? For example, the build-in libstd, when using `RUSTFLAGS='-C prefer-dynamic'`, the libstd will also be linked dynamically, which is not what I expected.

Answer (score 0):

`-C prefer-dynamic` doesn't actually affect how crates are built, only how they're searched for. In addition to that setting (which is how you get `std` to be linked dynamically so that it can be resolved to appear exactly once), what you need to do is add this to **the `Cargo.toml` of the dependency** which you want to link dynamically (in your case, `engine`):

```
[lib]
crate-type = ["dylib"]
```

This will tell Cargo that the crate can only be a Rust DLL (those have an unstable ABI, so you can't use them with code built by a different compiler version or with different compilation settings – the special ugly name prevents you from doing that).

If you want the `engine` crate to be able to exist in both incarnations, you can do what [Bevy](https://bevyengine.org/) does with its `dynamic` feature flag that turns the engine into a Rust DLL for fast incremental compiles. Thoroughly explaining its behavior is outside the scope of this answer, but you can check out Bevy's [`Cargo.toml`](https://github.com/bevyengine/bevy/blob/main/Cargo.toml) on the top-level crate, it's not a very complicated mechanism.

Comment: I have tried that approach, the cargo says 'cannot satisfy dependencies so `std` only shows up once', to get rid of this, I have to set `-C prefer-dynamic` or add 'rlib' to engine's crate-type list.

Comment: Looking into Bevy seems to be a nice suggestion, I will look into it.